# cordova mediapicker get actual file name

Tags: cordova

This cordova mediapicker will play the selected file from the picker.  The returned exportedurl seems to be a blob.  Is it possible to get the actual file name from the picker?  I want to use it later to retrieve it from the file system.

```
window.plugins.mediapicker.getAudio(success99, error99, false, false, " ");
function success99(data) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    var blob = data.exportedurl;
    // filename = actual file name ??
    player1.setAttribute("src", blob);
    player1.play();
}
function error99(e) {
    alert("whoops: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cordova-plugin-file-chooser plugin returns a url.  The following will play the selected file:

```
function playselectedfile() {
    var success = function (data) {
        alert(data.url);
        var p = document.getElementById("player");
        p.src = data.url;
        p.currentTime = 0;
        p.play();
    };
    var error = function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    };
    filechooser.open({ "mime": "audio/*" }, success, error);
    //filechooser.open({}, success, error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cordova-ourcodeworld-filebrowser Plugin has a filePicker that returns the filename as follows:

```
function androidfilepicker() {
    // Single file selector
    window.OurCodeWorld.Filebrowser.filePicker.single({
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.length) {
                // No file selected
                return;
            }
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
            filename = data[0];
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("whoops");
        },
        startupPath: "/storage/emulated/0/Music"
    });
}
```

As shown it will start with the musicLibrary in your Android.